# "The system cannot find the file specified." when running ECS Fargate task

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to run a Fargate (Windows) task on AWS ECS but it fails as soon as it ends it's "PENDING" state. I am not sure what I am missing. There is only 1 possible file that could cause this - `Wait-Service.ps1` but I don't see why it shouldn't be found.

The `Wait-Service.ps1` file is located in `bin/Debug` folder.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# escape=\

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN "mkdir C:\temp"

WORKDIR "C:/service"

COPY bin/Debug/ .

RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/installutil.exe" /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack ./SprProductionDataService.exe; \
  Set-Service -Name "\"SprProductionDataService\"" -StartupType Automatic; 

#The container stays up as long as this process is running.
CMD "C:/service/Wait-Service.ps1" -ServiceName "SprProductionDataService" -StartupTimeout 10 -AllowServiceRestart;
```

I only see this error message (in the AWS Console):

```
Status reason   CannotStartContainerError: CannotStartContainerError: 
hcs::System::CreateProcess 5d85964e54844ae0ad18140057019deb-4109322994: 
The system cannot find the file specified.: unknown
```

**UPDATE**:

I tried to run the container pulling it from the ECR repo and it does fail as well:

```
PS D:\_Code\SPRProductionDataService\SprProductionDataService> docker run --name sprprod -it spr-production-service-dev-ecr:latest 208555724522.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/spr-production-service-dev-ecr:latest powershell
docker: Error response from daemon: container e1658203aca736881659e1a5445e8d0ec549ccf94fe2f2952012752e330d9826 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7FACA9F4B: (caller: 00007FF7FAC5E13A) Exception(2) tid(3a4) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

Comment: Hi, maybe considering using [Qovery](https://www.qovery.com) would be the best thing for you?

Comment: @eVoxmusic thank you for the message. However, adding yet another (paid) tool to our team just to deploy that project would not be acceltable. We use Terraform company wide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem here is the way ENTRYPOINT/CMD was specified.

In first Dockerfile you had specified CMD in `shell` form.
In Second Dockerfile you had specified ENTRYPOINT and CMD in `exec` form. refer - [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile#run)

Basically, ECS Fargate runs containerd runtime and this runtime is not good while handling the shell form.

There is an open github [issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1556#issuecomment-1040891854) which describes the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

After digging a bit more, I found out that I missed to specify the `ENTRYPOINT` of the container which in my case is `powershell`. The bellow `dockerfile` worked for me:

```
# escape=\

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN "mkdir C:\temp"

WORKDIR "C:/service"

COPY bin/Debug/ .

# For debugging purposes only
#RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "TelnetClient"

RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/installutil.exe" /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack ./SprProductionDataService.exe; \
  Set-Service -Name "SprProductionDataService" -StartupType Automatic; 

#The container stays up as long as this process is running.
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe"]
CMD ["C:/service/Wait-Service.ps1", "-ServiceName", "SprProductionDataService", "-StartupTimeout", "10", "-AllowServiceRestart"];
```

Comment: thank you.  this non-shell syntax is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Can I build this image on a mac?